# ESP-IDF 5 self made Component cannot find driver/gpio.h

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, platformio, esp-idf

I created a new project from scratch with PlatformIO in VSCode using the ESP-IDF framework.

i have this structure

```
/
|-components
| |-include
| |-src
|
|-include
|
|-lib
|
|-src
|
|-test
```

in the src folder the main file is present.
If in that main file in include "driver/gpio.h"
it is working perfectly, i can access the GPIO.

Now when i move the code to my component in the components folder, the compiler apparently cannot find the "driver/gpio.h"

```
In file included from components\mypirComponent\src\mypirComponent.cpp:1:
components\mypirComponent\include/mypirComponent.hpp:9:10: fatal error: driver/gpio.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include "driver/gpio.h"
      |
```

I don't seem to find what is causing this in the platformio / ESP-IDF toolchain.
what should i do to fix this?

Comment: where is `driver/gpio.h` located in your filesystem?

Comment: It is located in my c:\users\ladb\esp\esp-idf\components\driver\gpio\gpio.h

Comment: Please show a CMakeLists.txt for a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Include in the CMakeLists.txt file. the IDF doesn't add it automatically. I don't know the technical reason, but this fixed my problem.

```
idf_component_register(SRCS ${SOURCE_FILES}
                       REQUIRES driver
                       INCLUDE_DIRS "src")
```